# RRD Tool Graph is not generating correct for one week and yearly

Tags: rrdtool

I have a case where I have collected SNMP data and stored it via rrdtool.

for daily and weekly graph is coming correct but when i see monthly and yearly it is showing only that day portion not correct graph as shown below.

Daily Graph code is : (working correct)

/usr/bin/rrdtool graph /opt/elitecore/ManageEngine/AppManager11/working/graphs/daily-tps.png -v "TPS" -t "TIME" DEF:tps1=/root/graphs/Total_TPS.rrd:TPS:MAX -s -86400 CDEF:tps2=tps1,300,* LINE1:tps2#ff0000:TOTAL_TPS GPRINT:tps2:LAST:"Cur: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:AVERAGE:"Avg: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:MAX:"Max: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:MIN:"Min: %5.2lf\t\t\t"

Monthly Graph code is : (not coming graph as expected)

/usr/bin/rrdtool graph /opt/elitecore/ManageEngine/AppManager11/working/graphs/monthly-tps.png -v "TPS" -t "WEEK" DEF:tps1=/root/graphs/Total_TPS.rrd:TPS:MAX -s -2592000 CDEF:tps2=tps1,300,* LINE1:tps2#ff0000:TOTAL_TPS GPRINT:tps2:LAST:"Cur: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:AVERAGE:"Avg: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:MAX:"Max: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:MIN:"Min: %5.2lf\t\t\t"

Yearly Graph code is : (not coming graph as expected)

/usr/bin/rrdtool graph /opt/elitecore/ManageEngine/AppManager11/working/graphs/yearly-tps.png -v "TPS" -t "MONTH" DEF:tps1=/root/graphs/Total_TPS.rrd:TPS:MAX -s -31536000 CDEF:tps2=tps1,300,* LINE1:tps2#ff0000:TOTAL_TPS GPRINT:tps2:LAST:"Cur: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:AVERAGE:"Avg: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:MAX:"Max: %5.2lf" GPRINT:tps2:MIN:"Min: %5.2lf\t\t\t"

Kindly let me know if i am doing any wrong.

yours Faithfully

Jignesh Dholakiya

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the images for the non-working graphs, and also the structure of the RRD file (using `rrdtool info`).  This would let us seeif the problem relates to incorrect RRA definitions, and to see visually what you mean by the graph being wrong.

For example, it may be that the MAX RRA is simply not long enough to hold a year's worth of data in all the available resolutions.

Comment: Dear Steve, Thanks for your response.. unfortunately i am unable to upload images as i have require 10 reputation for the same. could you please let me know how can i check rrdtool information... i am using linux system where i have installed RPM for rrdtool and using the rrdtool from crontab schedule.

Comment: use `rrdtool info foo.rrd` to obtain the RRD structure of the `foo.rrd` file, which will show us the interval, the number of RRAs defined, and their lengths.  Although you cannot uplaod images yet, you should be able to use free online services like `photobucket.com` to upload an image and post a URL here to view it.

Comment: Dear Steve,

Thanks for your favourable reply. below is Graph link.

Graph Link
http://s45.photobucket.com/user/jkdholakiya/media/TPS_zpsbe5f5d8f.png.html

Sincerely Thanks,
Jignesh Dholakiya.

Comment: Dear Steve, 

below is the rrdtool info commnand output.

rrdtool  info Total_TPS.rrd 
filename = "Total_TPS.rrd"
rrd_version = "0003"
step = 300
last_update = 1410433802
header_size = 584
ds[TPS].index = 0
ds[TPS].type = "ABSOLUTE"
ds[TPS].minimal_heartbeat = 600
ds[TPS].min = 0.0000000000e+00
ds[TPS].max = 5.0000000000e+02
ds[TPS].last_ds = "24"
ds[TPS].value = 2.2656499547e-01
ds[TPS].unknown_sec = 0
rra[0].cf = "MAX"
rra[0].rows = 1500
rra[0].cur_row = 1390
rra[0].pdp_per_row = 1
rra[0].xff = 5.0000000000e-01
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].value = NaN
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].unknown_datapoints = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

The graph only shows five day's worth of data in the graphs because that is all the data there is in your RRD.  Your RRD is configured to automatically discard any data older than this.

**Explanation**

The graphs show that your RRD currently only has 6 days' worth of data to display.  As you cannot graph data which you do not have, the graphs show what they do have, and nothing for the rest.

Your `rrdtool info` gives this for RRA definitions (trimmed for clarity):

```
step = 300
rra[0].cf = "MAX" 
rra[0].rows = 1500 
rra[0].pdp_per_row = 1  
rra[0].xff = 5.0000000000e-01
```

This means that you have a single RRA, type MAX, which has 1pdp per row and 1500 rows.

As a result, your RRA is (step)x(pdp per row)x(number of rows) long, which is 1500x300 seconds, which is a little over 5 days.

Since your RRD only has a single RRA, all of your graph functions will use this one -- doing additional consolidation on the fly if necessary.  Thus all your graphs use this single RRA.

However, your RRA is only 5-and-a-bit days long.  Therefore, data will be expired and discarded when it is this old.  As a result, only the last 5-and-a-bit days' worth of data are available at any time for graphing, which is what you see in the graphs.

**Solution:**

You need to keep the data for longer.  There are two ways to do this --

1. Increase the length of the existing RRA
2. Create additional RRAs to hold the consolidated data for the lower-resolution graphs.

Option 1 is the simplest, as you can use `rrdtool tune` to grow the size of RRA number 0.  However, it is very expensive in disk space (since you will be keeping the detailed data for the entire time period), plus it is expensive in CPU (RRDtool will have to consolidate on the fly when making yearly graphs).  This option is only recommended if you really need the high-resolution data for the entire period -- such as if you are calculating 95th Percentiles, for example.

Option 2 is the best.  You add a new RRA, with the same CF but more pdp_per_row, for each graph you will be wishing to create.  For a Weekly graph, use pdp_per_row=6 (for a half-hour consolidation), for Monthly use 24 (two-hourly) and for Yearly, use 288 (daily consolidation).  As time goes by, the data will be consolidated up into these new RRA, and the graph functions will use them in preference.  This is less computationally expensive, and uses less disk space; however you lose the high-resolution data over time, and your historical data will not be automatically consolidated into the new RRAs.  Also, you cannot just add a new RRA to an existing RRD file -- you will need to either create a new RRD, or use a tool such as rrdmerge.

Comment: Dear Steve, Thanks for your excellent answer. i would like to follow option 2 for weekly and yearly graph. could you let me know is there any way to create new RRA without loosing my current data ?  Thanks !! Jignesh Dholakiya

Comment: There's no easy way.  However, if you create a new RRD file with all the correctly sized RRAs, you can then use the rrdmerge utility included with Routers2 to merge the two -- it will preserve the old data where possible. See http://www.steveshipway.org/software